# long texts got hidden, While exporting PDF from Birt

Tags: birt

I'm using BIRT as reporting tool. while exporting the datas from the BIRT report as PDF. the long texts got hidden. I have attached the image.
[image]
from the above image in the MM Group column the long texts got hidden. is there any way to overcome it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When autowrapping is activated it should wrap to a new line. I'm not sure why it doesn't do it.

I think it is because there are no spaces in the text. It sees the "100000,100200,OVCR..." as one long word which doesn't get wrapped.

Are you concatenating these values yourself? Just add in a space after every comma.
Otherwise replace comma's with comma-space with code like:

```
row["MMGroup"].split(",").join(", ");
```

You can simply modify the data element in the table.
(javascript function replace() will only replace the first occurrence)